# How to Switch Packages to Different Repository?

Tags: gnome, ppa, repository

I installed `gnome-shell` from a 3rd party repository a while ago, but now it's in the official repository.  How do I switch it and all it's dependencies to the official repository?  I tried removing the other PPA and `apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, but it doesn't seem to detect any change.  What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ppa-purge` (not installed by default) to disable the PPA, that will automatically revert your packages to the official versions.

Comment: I ran it (`sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing`), and it seemed to do something, but those packages still show up as under that PPA.  Why?

Comment: Things were busting, I opted to reinstall.  Everything's fixed now, but I'll bet if I hadn't messed with stuff before you replied, this would have fixed the problem.  Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the other PPA from your sources and still don't get any update, that probably means that the version in the PPA is newer than the one in the official repository (even if you remove the PPA, the packages remain installed).

To make sure about that, you can use the `apt-cache policy <package_name>` command. In my case, it shows that the version available from the official repositories is `3.2.1-0ubuntu1`. In your case it should show that that version is available, but you have installed a different one.

If you really want to have the same version as in the official repositories, you can downgrade the package. However, I wouldn't recommend that since my understanding is that the PPA version isn't causing any problem. Anyway, to downgrade the package, run the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell=3.2.1-0ubuntu1
```

Note: Some other packages might be installed/removed during the downgrade process if dependencies have changed for the two different versions of the package.

Comment: There's a very big tree of dependencies, and it failed when I tried to downgrade because of version conflicts.  How can I downgrade _all_ packages from that repository at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch packages to a different repository. If you don't need the PPA any more, remove it using the Software Sources interface (the commands you posted don't remove repositories).